# What is wrong with my method of exporting csvs?

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to export some data from the console into a csv file on my desktop. I created an export_csv method in my model to run from the console

```
def export_csv

  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << [
      'Animal', 'Subanimal'
    ]
    Animal.all.each do |animal|
      subanimals = animal.children
      unless subanimals.blank?
        subanimals.each do |subanimal|
          csv << [
            animal.name, subanimal.name
          ]
        end
      end
    end
  end


  filename = "animals_and_subanimals.csv"
  CSV.open(filename, 'w') do |csv|
    csv << csv_string
  end
end
```

but it is breaking and giving me this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<String:0x007f90ce247000>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv_string` is already a CSV formatted string.  Just write it out to disk like so:

```
File.open(filename, 'w') {|f| f.puts csv_string}
```

Your last CSV block is what's throwing you off.

Alternatively, create the file as you go instead of building up a (potentially?) large string in memory.

Comment: Thanks! The error is now gone but in console it shows that it finds all the data and then at the end returns nil. I'm not sure what is supposed to happen but there is no save dialog or file being stored anywhere on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here, let me try to clean it up for you:

```
def export_csv
  filename = "animals_and_subanimals.csv"

  CSV.open(filename, 'w') do |csv|
    csv << ['Animal', 'Subanimal']
    Animal.all.each do |animal|
      subanimals = animal.children
      unless subanimals.blank?
        subanimals.each do |subanimal|
          csv << [animal.name, subanimal.name]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```